# How to best select a PHP framework - Laravel, Symfony, Zend, Etc

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework, laravel-4, zend-framework2

My company wants to adopt a PHP framework and I am being asked to decide which one to use going forward.

Our requirements are simple

1. It must be part of the php-fig
2. Must look like it will be around & active for at least another 10 years
3. Must have a healthy community
4. Must have libraries/bundles/modules/packages/etc or whatever they are called that we can draw on to speed up development.

Using the above criteria I have found frameworks that I like

- Symfony -> Seems to be an industry leader / feels a little over engineered
- Laravel -> very popular at the moment and easy to use/understand
- Zend -> Zend 1 hurt my feelings and I have never really forgiven it, I am just not comfortable with Zend

I would like to use Laravel but point 2 above concerns me as its really driven by one person, even though there is s strong community, that one person still has too strong an influence its not like Drupal where if Dries goes away the community will not crumble, I feel that if Tyler goes then Laravel will fall. And as much as I like it I don't want to tie my company to that wagon.

**This question is NOT about which framework is better BUT how to best decide on selecting a framework for your Company**

Comment: This is a very broad request.  The answer as how to decide which is best is subjective.  Pick the framework you best feel will meet your project needs.  On a side note, I don't understand how requirement #1 really applied.  What is php-fig membership of a framework going to do for your project??

Comment: I would suggest you also take a look at: CakePHP, Yii and (I just recently discovered it) "Fat-Free framework" which seems REALLY apropiated for some situations: http://fatfreeframework.com/

Comment: So you are saying pick framework per project? I have 15 projects on the go at work at the moment all running old code some on zend some on condeigniter etc, I want to standardize this - so picking a framework per project seems wrong, should we not be a "zend" or "symfony" development house

Comment: @user3408844 in a perfect world you should use the framework that best suits the project as Crackertastic suggest, but unfortunately in real world situations you don't have enough time or resources to spend time learning multiple frameworks. But since you have 15 projects, why not using different frameworks and have each team learn their specific framework?

Comment: @user3408844 I understand the reasoning for wanting to standardize under a single framework, which there is nothing wrong with.  However as I said, you will need to pick the framework right for the project.  Is every project so big that you need the robustness of Zend, or are there projects that are small enough that a micro-framework, like Slim will do the job.  These are questions that you and your team should ask regarding your projects.  Maybe specialize in more than one, if you have a team.  Flexibility will help you in the end.  What if a client demands a specific framework be used?

Comment: @crackertastic This is closest to answer as it address how to select rather than which is better, see bold section of the question

Comment: I would go for Symfony 2 over laravel and Zend but it also depends on what you really need it for. For comaprison between symfony 2 and laravel visit this link: http://vschart.com/compare/laravel/vs/symfony

Answer (score 11):

We can't tell you what is the best framework *for you* - only you can decide that. But you've mostly answered your question in your description of your options - it seems like Laravel is what you're leaning towards. Plus, it's an open source project, if the creator were to throw in the towel I'm sure there would be enough momentum for others to pick it up.

One additional point I'd make: 10 years is a long time in web development - none of the frameworks in your list existed 10 years ago. It's good to try and choose something with some longevity, but I wouldn't try and plan too far ahead.

Comment: I'm not a fan of these frameworks exactly because a person or company have to re-learn everything in less than 10 years, when the hype goes out and another "new best" comes. Or stick to an outdated and probably not even updated set of libraries, one prone to drown. Isn't php safer, on the long run? For a company that may exist for decades, why not stick to pure php and made their own libraries for security, database management, etc, or use any set of libraries already there. Could it be advantageous, depending on the team, perhaps?

Comment: @Rodrigo Because of that I would only use a Framework for the most basic things like HTTP requesting, Session handling, etc. and not become too dependend of the Framework. So you could switch all your business logic to another framework (even proprietary) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Tons of articles have answered this question already. One written a little over a year ago should give you a decent idea of how to make your decistion:

http://jonathanmh.com/best-php-mvc-frameworks-of-2013/

Comment: The question is about how to best "select" a framework not which is the best framework,

Comment: i think "choose" is the correct word to use here ;P